# How to resolve Kubernetes Deployment warning?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.20.2
Server Version: v1.19.6-eks-49a6c0
```

I have the following Deployment manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stats-service
  namespace: my-system
  labels:
    app: stats-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stats-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stats-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stats-service
        image: 0123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stats-service:3.12.1
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1024m"
            cpu: "512m"
          limits:
            memory: "2048m"
            cpu: "1024m"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 5000
          protocol: TCP
       startupProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /manage/health
            port: 5000
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /manage/health
            port: 5000
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /manage/health
            port: 5000
          failureThreshold: 6
          periodSeconds: 10
        env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: test
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: "my_java_opts"
```

When I apply it I get the following warning, and the Pod never gets created. What does it mean and how to resolve it? In my case, I'm running and EKS Fargate (only) cluster. Thanks!

```
$ kubectl describe pod stats-service-797784dfd5-tvh84
...
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  12s   kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"read init-p: connection reset by peer\"": unknown
```

NOTES:

- Seems like the warning is related to the `spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits` block. If I remove that, the Pod gets created.
- A lot of the solutions I read online say to reset Docker, which obviously can't apply to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong notations for your resources. As per [Meaning of memory](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-units-in-kubernetes):

> Limits and requests for memory are measured in bytes. You can express
> memory as a plain integer or as a fixed-point number using one of
> these suffixes: E, P, T, G, M, K. You can also use the power-of-two
> equivalents: Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki.

If you want,

- Requests:

  - 1GB RAM
  - 0.5 vCPU/Core
- Limits:

  - 2GB RAM
  - 1 vCPU/Core

This should work:

```
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1G"
            cpu: "0.5"
          limits:
            memory: "2G"
            cpu: "1"
```

The following is equivalent, but using different notations:

```
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1024M"
            cpu: "500m"
          limits:
            memory: "2048M"
            cpu: "1000m"
```

*Notice that the above example uses `M` for memory, not `m`.*

Comment: Thank you so much. That was indeed the issue.

Comment: but what if a person specify the memory as "fractional" value. like "2.2G" , how would that be taken ?

Comment: use 2252M for 2.2G to avoid fractions.